# touchpad stops moving after some period of properly working

Tags: touchpad, 20.04

As it was said, the touchpad stops working properly after some period of working: the pointer doesn't move, but the buttons still work. The restarting with

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

doesn't help.
But after full restarting, it begins working properly.

This problem was on Ubuntu 19.10 and still exist after updating to the 20.04

Please, help me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, no touchpad motion but left and right click work, with 20.04 after perfect performance for years on 16.04!

Running 'xinput list' showed a PS/2 Generic Mouse device, that upon disabling (xinput disable id), would reproduce my issue.

It turns out I had both xserver-org-input-synaptics and xserver-org-input-libinput installed! I got rid of synaptics, and havn't had the issue since.

Comment: I confirm this. Removing `xserver-org-input-synaptics` fixes the issue. That must be a bug that it is still installed in 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and removing `xserver-org-input-synaptics` fixed it.

I found this: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection](http://%20DebuggingTouchpadDetection)

It may be useful to you in case you find other issues?